# Dados não estão sendo mostrados na view

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando renderizar alguns dados em uma tabela, usando VueJS. Estou fazendo uma requisição com o axios da seguinte maneira:

```
export default {
data() {
     return {
         movimentos: []
     };
},
mounted() {
        axios.get('urlDaAPIAqui/movimento')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.movimentos = response.data
        })
    }
}
```

Os dados estão vindo em um Array, mas estou com problemas para renderizar na tabela:

```
<tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="movimento in movimentos">
                    <td>{{ movimento.mov_codigo }}</td>
                    <td>{{  }}</td>
                    <td>{{  }}</td>
                    <td>{{  }}</td>
                </tr>
```

Array retornado:

[image: Array]

Os dados retornados da requisição são mov_codigo, mov_descricao, mov_tipo e mov_valor, já tentei utilizar todos dentro dos td's e não funcionou.

Resposta do Postman:

```
{
    "movimento": [
        {
            "mov_codigo": "m01",
            "cta_codigo": 1,
            "mov_tipo": "D",
            "mov_descricao": "Combustivel",
            "mov_valor": 154.56
        },
```

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Já tentou dar um **push** no movimentos invés de atribuir o valor do response?

Comment: tipo this.movimentos.push(response.data) ?

Comment: Ahan, Isso mesmo.

Comment: Tentei agora e não funcionou, no meu console.log a resposta é essa: {error: false, data: Array(12)} Um array com 12 itens.

Comment: Então tem algum problema com o response. Posta o array que é retornado aí na pergunta.

Comment: Vou postar uma foto de como ele se parece porque fica ruim de pegar no console.log.

Comment: Cara ta meio estranho isso aí, se abrir o mov_codigo tem o que, dentro desses parenteses?

Comment: Cara abre esse response aí inteiro pra gente analisar, to achando que o response não é um array não.

Comment: @LeAndrade abri no postman, parece que é um objeto, e dentro tem um Array. Vou botar um exemplo.

Comment: Então, foi o que suspeitei, é um array de objetos, aí já muda tudo!

Comment: Hmmm, pois é. Alguma sugestão pra iterar?

Comment: Resolvi aqui, passei response.data.movimento e funcionou, muito obrigado de qualquer forma pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido adicionando o response.data.movimento à requisição no axios:

```
axios.get('https://projeto-bolsa.herokuapp.com/movimento')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.movimento)
                this.movimentos = response.data.movimento
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
```